# Why is axios trying to connect on port 80 and not 8080?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, axios

I am running a Node/Express back-end with a `vue` front-end on a Windows 10 machine. I did install `iisnode` because I thought I would serve `server.js` using IIS, but at the moment I am in development and would like to leave IIS out of it.

However, when I make a production build of the website and run `node ./dist/server.js`, the Node/Express server runs on `port 8080` and the homepage loads fine.

When I go to a product page that makes an `axios` call, I am getting an error that:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config: {
    url: '/api/int/v1/product/10800',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1'
    },
...... // more stuff here
isAxiosError: true //<== is an axios issue?
```

I don't understand why it is trying to connect on port 80 instead of just going to `http://localhost:8080/api/int/v1/product/10800`

**server.js** does this:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And I even set the `port` when running the build script like this:

```
"build:server": "cross-env PORT=8080 NODE_ENV=production webpack --config build/webpack.server.config.js"
```

In the `console` log it even says `Server is listening on port 8080`

Comment: use axios BASE_URL configuration and define the port there.

Comment: @EduardoSousa thank you that solved it :)

Comment: great, posting as answer so everyone with the same question get the answer straight away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure the axios BASE_URL, defining the port there e.g.:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```